# How many methods dot.Net delegates have?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, delegates

I'm curious what delegates methods exists? For instance I'm aware of Asynchronous method calls, like this:

```
class Program {
   // define a delegate
   delegate int MyDelegate(String s);

   static void Main(string[] args) {
      // create the delegate
      MyDelegate del = new MyDelegate(myMethod);

      // invoke the method asynchronously
      IAsyncResult result = del.BeginInvoke("foo", null, null);

      // get the result of that asynchronous operation
      int retValue = del.EndInvoke(result);

      }
   }
```

Here are "BeginInvoke()" and "EndInvoke()" methods, but is there any other delegates methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All delegate types derive from [`System.Delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx) (just like all enum types derive from `System.Enum`), which means they all have all the methods on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate_methods.aspx).

The noteworthy ones are:

[`DynamicInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx)
[`GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx)

A `static` method of the `Delegate` type that is very interesting and totally worth knowing about (as it can turn poorly performing reflected code into zippy compiled code) is [`CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx).

Also: [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99bthb1z.aspx) and [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.gethashcode.aspx) (yes, they are overridden).

And until recently I was honestly not aware of the [`Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.method.aspx) and [`Target`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.target.aspx) properties, but I can imagine they'd be quite useful in certain specific contexts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another question. I followed your link, and in MulticastDelegate Class reference in msdn library, is mentioned that "common language runtime provides two special methods: BeginInvoke and EndInvoke". Just of a curiosity, do you know where are declared those methods?